# Resample a DataFrame in day and night

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
                       column
2015-01-01 00:00:00    27.38
2015-01-01 01:00:00    23.37
2015-01-01 02:00:00    19.33
2015-01-01 03:00:00    17.66
2015-01-01 04:00:00    17.53
2015-01-01 05:00:00    18.07
2015-01-01 06:00:00    25.23
2015-01-01 07:00:00    26.80
2015-01-01 08:00:00    26.97
2015-01-01 09:00:00    26.29
```

and so on, every hour from 2015-01-01 00:00 to 2017-12-31 23:00

I'd like to resample this, so that I take the mean of the "night hours" and the mean of the "day hours". I define night 18:00 to 07:00 and day as 07:00 to 18:00. Thus resulting in a DataFrame like

```
                     column
2015-01-01 07:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2015-01-01 07:00:00)
2015-01-01 18:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-01 07:00:00 to 2015-01-01 18:00:00)
2015-01-02 07:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-01 18:00:00 to 2015-01-02 07:00:00)
2015-01-02 18:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-02 07:00:00 to 2015-01-02 18:00:00)
2015-01-03 07:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-02 18:00:00 to 2015-01-03 07:00:00)
2015-01-03 18:00:00    x    (This would be the mean of the values from 2015-01-03 07:00:00 to 2015-01-03 18:00:00)
```

I hope that it is clear what I'm asking. Please let me know if I shall explain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround could be as follows:

```py
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0]+' day' if int(x[-8:-6])<=7 else x.split()[0]+' night')
df.groupby(0)[1].mean()
```

Basically I am replacing the time in `hh:mm:ss` to `day` or `night`. This would allow me to easily group them and perform any  operation that you want.

Comment: Ah, this assumes that the index is in its separate column. This isnt true in my case, but I guess I could do some work around

Comment: You can reset the index using `df.reset_index()`. and then apply the method...

Comment: If this answer helped then please consider upvoting it.

Comment: My index is a datetime index. I'm getting errors that "'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
"

Comment: Just convert it into string using `.astype(str)`

Comment: I'd like to keep the datetime index, since I'd like to perform a resample with ffill on hourly basis later on

Comment: You can always convert it back. It's easy since days correspond to 07:00 and nights to 18:00. Then you can use the ffill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214259/discussion-between-olba12-and-paradoxlover).